# Ubuntu Server proper SSH etiquette

Tags: ssh, security, email, raspberrypi, webserver

I am using ubuntu server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 as a Web-Server and eventually Mail-Server. The default user is called ubuntu and I was wondering if that is the account I am meant to SSH in, or if I should rename it, delete it or create a new user with the name I want. Are there any security concerns related to actively using the ubuntu user for remote access? Also, if I set up an email address using this server as johndoe@example.com and my SSH user is called johndoe, will that cause any problems since I will have to login for SSH using "ssh johndoe@example.com"? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**User Accounts**: You have an 'ubuntu' account simply because the root account is locked. You need *some* account to be able to login for the first time. There is nothing special about the 'ubuntu' account -- it's just like every other admin account. You can use it --or a different account that you create-- as you please.

- Creating a new admin user to replace 'ubuntu' is very easy.
- Advice: If you decide to use the Ubuntu account, CHANGE THE PASSWORD. Don't make an intruder happy by keeping the default password.

**SSH**: Our usual advice is to ALWAYS use key-based authentication for SSH connections across the internet. Never passwords. Automated attacks against password-protected ssh servers are just too easy.

Comment: So can I just disable the ubuntu account outright? Also, when I do "sudo -i" it logs me in as root. Does that mean that I enabled root accidentally? Thank you for your help!

Comment: AksUbuntu is poorly suited to follow-up questions in comments. This is not a thread-based or coversational venue. 1) Yes, you can...after you create another user. 2) No, you didn't. A root prompt is not a root login.